# Regex to validate both dd-mm-yy and dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that validates both `dd-mm-yyyy` and `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss` at the same time.

For example, 
`28-02-2018` and `28-02-2018 03:30:55` should be validated correctly by a single regex.

I created two separated regex so far, one for the date and the other one for time and I do not understand how to combine of these so that it'll work for both the cases.

dd-mm-yyyy, dd/mm/yyyy, dd.mm.yyyy -

```
^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-\.]([12][0-9]\d\d)$
```

hh:mm:ss -

```
^(0?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])[\:]([0-5][0-9])[\:]([0-5][0-9])$
```

I handled incorrect day and month numbers. Leap years are not a problem for me.

How would I do it?

Comment: Have you tried to insert both regex in separate parenthesis then insert pipe between them?Like:   (regex1) | (regex2)

Comment: `x( y)?` where `x` = date regex and `y` = time regex

Comment: `validated correctly by a single regex` ... a single regex really can't do complete validation.  Case in point: How would your regex know about leap years, and that every 4 years February has an extra day?  If you can just try using it in your Python code, and then catch an exception, that might be a better way to do this.

Comment: Your regex is also handling single day/month inputs. Is this a requirement?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an optional part... for example

```
^\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d( \d\d:\d\d:\d\d)?$
```

The meaning is

- `^` start of string
- `\d\d` two digits
- `-` a dash
- `\d\d-\d\d\d\d` two more digits another dash and four digits
- `(` beginning of a sub-expression
- a space
- `\d\d:\d\d:\d\d` a time in 99:99:99 format
- `)` end of sub-expression
- `?` zero or one instances of the sub-expression
- `$` the end of the string

the `?` is used in this example to make the time part "optional".

If you want to accept different separators, but only accept uniform cases (i.e. refuse 12-03.2018) then you can use a slightly more complex approach, for example:

```
^\d\d?([-./])\d\d?\1\d\d(\d\d)?( \d\d\:\d\d:\d\d)?$
```

- `^` start of string
- `\d\d?` one or two digits
- `([-./])` one separator chosen between `-`, `.` or `/`
- `\d\d?` one or two digits
- `\1` the same separator we used before (backref to group 1)
- `\d\d(\d\d)?` two or four digits for the year
- `( \d\d:\d\d:\d\d)?` the optional time part
- `$` the end of string

Comment: Not working with "-" and "." as separators and is also not working with single digit day/month. Again, the question is ambiguous.

Comment: @tk78: i thought the main problem was making the time optional "combining" two different regular expressions. I've added a more complex case accepting different (but uniform) separators for the date and two or four digit years.

Answer (score 1):

Comes from [正则应用之——日期正则表达式](https://blog.csdn.net/lxcnn/article/details/4362500), this regex contains all the leap years and month days. After litter format change, the answer should be:

```
^(?:(?:(?:(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[\/\-\.](0[1-9]|1[0-2])|(29|30)[\/\-\.](0[13-9]|1[0-2])|(31)[\/\-\.](0[13578]|1[02]))[\/\-\.]([1-2][0-9]{3}))|(?:(29)[\/\-\.](02)[\/\-\.]([1-2][0-9](?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])00)))(?: ((?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:2[0-3])):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))?$
```

[image: regex tester]

But please note, the author suggest us not to do that. You'd better write regex to match all the datetime numbers, then validate them by code.

Comment: This regex isn't working if day or month is just one number. The regex in the question is implying this. Don't know whether is a real requirement though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,hope it will help

```
import re   

re.findall(r'\d\d\s(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s\d{4}', text)
```

Comment: Not working with "." and "/" as separators

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is the following:

```
(\d?\d[\/\.-]){2}\d{4}(\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})?
```

It's matching all of your constellations.

If you want to validate the dates, use dateutil.parser.parse(). Like so:

```
def is_valid_date(date_as_txt):
try:
    parse(date_as_txt)
    return True
except:
    return False
```

The function returns True for valid dates and False for invalid ones.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the pipe symbol at the end of the first expression to include the second expression.

```
import re
text = '20-10-2013'
text2 = '20-02-1939 20:20:20'
pattern = re.compile(r'^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\.\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\.\-]([12][0-9]\d\d)($|\s(0?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])[\:](0?[0-5][0-9])[\:](0?[0-5][0-9]))')
matches = pattern.finditer(text2)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
    print(match.group())
```

Result:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 19), match='20-02-1939 20:20:20'>
20-02-1939 20:20:20
```